# Integration Services Catalogs

Tags: ssis

I have deployed a SSIS Package to the Integration Services Catalogs. The issue that I am having is that the flat files are generated locally on the server itself instead of on File server. The path for file generation is given as File server path but still the files are generated locally only.

Comment: To restate, the package generates a file on the SQL Server (SQL1) but the desire is for the files to be created on File Server (FS2). When you state the path for the file generation is given as the File Server path, what exactly do you mean and how have you accomplished this?

Comment: I have deployed the package to to the Integration Services Catalogs and when i execute the package it actually load the files locally on "D" drive instead of loading the files to the file server path specified. I'm thinking it has something to do with variables on visual studio..

Comment: you Need to give unified path rather than drive name like C:/D:

Answer (score 0):

you can you set variable to set location of folder
https://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-export-files-from-sql-table-to.html